# How to get the id of selected option in <select> in my case?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors, dom-events

I have a < select > field and a button in **index.html**:

```
<select id="mylist"></select>

<input type="button" id="btn" value="update">
```

The following **Javascript** will update the **options** of the < select > field when button is clicked:

```
var btn=$('#btn');
btn.click(function(){
     var optionList = GET_OBJECT_LIST(); //get an array of Object, object has id & name
     var select  = $("#mylist");

     select.empty();

     for(var i=0; i<optionList.length; i++){
       select.append("<option value=" + optionList[i].id+ ">" + optionList[i].name + "</option>");
     }

});
```

Things are fine until now.

Then, I would like to implement the feature that after `options` are updated, when mouse click on an **option** in the `<select>` field, I can get the object **id** (i.e. the `<option>` value) of the selected option. How to do it?

Comment: `id` is not `value`. They're distinct properties.

Comment: @Blender, if you check my post carefully, the id here is the object.id, I would like to get the object id of the selected option which represents an object in my case. I use <option value=object.id> in purpose. What I need is to get this object.id when mouse clicked on a certain option.

Answer (score 2):

This might work (not sure if it returns an array or not, so you'll find out):

```
$('#mylist').change(function() {
  var selected = $(this).find('option:selected');

  // Foo.
});
```

Comment: Hi, I can get the selected option value (i.e. the object.id) by access "selected[0].value", but what does this 0 means?

Comment: `[0]` is the array index. You can select multiple items, so they will be aggregated in the array. You can use `.find('option:selected:eq(0)');`, if you'd like, as it selects the first selected item.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out to use the following code which fits exactly what I want:

```
$('#mylist').change(function() {
  var selected_object_id = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('value');
  console.log(selected_object_id); //it directly returns to me the selected option represented object id
});
```